# Сортировка массива

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Здравствуйте!
Задача следующая, есть два массива один с текстом, второй с числами определяющими позицию этого текста. Для наглядности:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array('1a','2b','3c','4d','5e');
```

Массив "а" может изменяться и в зависимости от этого нужно отсортировать массив "б"
Т.е. при перемешивании может выйти такое:

```
$a = array(5,2,4,1,3);
$b = array('5e','2b','4d','1a','3c');
```

Но вот не могу найти функцию которая делал бы это "с коробки", а почему-то есть "чуйка" что подобное есть.
К примеру сейчас я сделал так:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($b as $value)
{
  $c[$a[$i]] = $b[$a[$i++]];
}
```

И в принципе получил желаемое, но вопрос есть ли все-же решение "из коробки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "с коробки"

Массивы имеют ключи:

```
$b = array('1a','2b','3c','4d','5e');
uasort($b, function() {return round(rand()*2-1);});
var_dump($b, array_keys($b));
```

-----

```
array(5) { 3 => "4d", 1 => "2b", 0 => "1a", 2 => "3c", 4 => "5e" } // array
array(5) { 3, 1, 0, 2, 4 } // array keys, для наглядности
```

Если вам принципиально начинать с единицы, то прописывайте ключи массиву, делов-то

```
array(1 => '1a', 2 => '2b',..
```

> чуйка

0_о